# Sending a TCP command by clicking a button on Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm new to Android programming so I don't know much about networking. What I want to do is make it so when I click a button, it sends a specific command through the network to a specific IP; Much like a network remote would.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well do you already have the TCP connection open?  You aren't giving us much to go by.

Comment: Not at the moment. I was hoping for an explained sample code. Most of the samples that I've seen don't explain the coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by reading the Oracle Socket docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html

It gives a nice general overview.  After that, make sure you enable the permission `INTERNET` in your Android project, otherwise any socket you try to create will just return `null`.

Once you have established a TCP socket, it seems like you just want to send command codes down to the server and have that do stuff.  To do this, it is just a simple:

```
try{
    <dataOutputStream>.write(BUFFER);
} catch(IOException e)
{
    //error code
}
```

where `buffer` is an integer constant for whatever command you are sending.  Be careful though because the `write()` method in this case will only write the least significant byte of the integer, so anything larger than 255 will not be sent.  There are several `write()` methods and you can pick the most appropriate one.